# how do you translate this ssh command into a ssh_config file?

Tags: linux, ssh, command, ssh-keys

I am trying to translate this ssh command into my ssh_config. What is the equivalant of -L in the ssh_config? I thought it was localForward but from the restuls i am getting it does not look that way.

**SSH command**

```
sudo ssh -i ~/.ssh/mySSHkey -L 81:<IP1>:81 -L 9200:<IP1>:9200  user@myhost.domain.com
```

**ssh_config entry**

```
Host logstash
        Hostname                <IP1>
        Port                    81
#        ForwardX11             yes
        LocalForward            81 <IP1>:81
        LocalForward            9200 <IP1>:9200
        User                    username
        IdentityFile            ~/.ssh/mySSHkey
        ServerAliveInterval     30
        ServerAliveCountMax     120
#       LogLevel                DEBUG3
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help developing software. You should consider asking on http://superuser.com/ or http://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Host tunnel
HostName database.example.com
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/john.example.key
LocalForward 9906 127.0.0.1:3306
User john
```

Equivalent of:

```
ssh -f -N -L 9906:127.0.0.1:3306 john@database.example.com
```

With the new config in place you can run:

```
ssh -f -N tunnel
```

Source: http://nerderati.com/2011/03/17/simplify-your-life-with-an-ssh-config-file/